How to Display Only the Video Codec Information Using MediaInfo CL in a Windows 10 Batch File
If I want to use Command Line (CL) Mediainfo.exe in a batch file to determine and display the video codec used to encode the video stream in a mkv container, how would that look. I know how to dump all of the info, but want to just display the video codec info.
I've been advised that this: MediaInfo.exe --Inform="Video;%Codec%" filename.mp4  will do the job, but it doesn't when executed from the command line it hangs for several seconds and then returns to the prompt with nothing displayed.
If this is not 'doable' with MediaInfo, or no one knows quite how to structure the string, I'd be glad to hear alternative approaches. For context, my batch file pauses, then I want it to display the encoding information of the specified file, and depending on what is displayed I either continue with a re-encoding process or abort.
I tried to display the encoding information using ffmpeg too, but was not successful with that approach either. Could be someone here knows how.

Please show what you have doe so far.

MediaInfo.exe --Inform="Video;%Codec%" filename.mp4
MediaInfo.exe --Inform="Video%%CodecID%%" filename.mp4
